# Use a Synonym on SQL Server for an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, synonym

Is it possible to use a Synonym in SQL Server to execute a Stored Procedure in a linked Oracle server?

I know I can execute the SP directly, and the following statement works correctly:

```
EXECUTE ('BEGIN PROCEDURE1; END;') AT [LinkedOracleServer];
```

But I'd like to be able to use a Synonym so that if the linked server name changes, I don't have to update all my code, just the Synonym. I've created a Synonym like so:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.ORA_PROC1 FOR [LinkedOracleServer]..[MYSCHEMA].[PROCEDURE1];
```

The Synonym was create correctly, but calling it with `EXECUTE dbo.ORA_PROC1` returns an error message:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LinkedOracleServer" returned message "Unspecified error".
>   Msg 7323, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error occurred while submitting the query text to OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LinkedOracleServer".

FYI, Synonyms for tables on the linked server work fine, so why not Stored Procedure?

```
CREATE SYNONYM ORA_TABLE1 FOR [LinkedOracleServer]..[MYSCHEMA].[TABLE1];
GO
SELECT * FROM ORA_TABLE1;
```

### Edit

After further testing, I discovered that

```
EXECUTE [LinkedOracleServer]..[MYSCHEMA].[PROCEDURE1]
```

returns the exact same error as above. So the problem is not necessarily with the Synonym itself, but with the syntax of executing that procedure.

Comment: please include the error message

Comment: @JonathonOgden Done. (Always good advice!)

Comment: just for the sake of clarity, you can execute this SP of yours directly, just not via the synonym? (didn't seem clear enough to me in your opening comments)

Comment: @JonathonOgden Yes, the first execute statement in the question works as expected.

Comment: You don't have a database listed in the synonym definition.  Objects are not checked during definition, just at run time, so it is very possible to have the CREATE work but the EXEC fail.  I would try CREATE SYNONYM ORA_PROC1 FOR [LinkiedOracleServer].[LOSDatabase].[SCEMA].[PROCEDURE1] and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli There is no separate database and schema in Oracle. See my updated example above for how tables work.

Comment: Make sure that Procedure1 on the Oracle side is the actual object and not a synonym to the object because you can't link a synonym to a remote synonym. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187552.aspx Also, make sure that you have granted the correct rights to your synonym

Comment: You could create a stored procedure in your current database that performs the operation `EXECUTE ('BEGIN PROCEDURE1; END;') AT [LinkedOracleServer];`

Comment: @rdbradshaw Interesting idea. Doesn't really solve the problem as asked, but should be just as easy to work with as synonyms...

Comment: @Doug The error you are getting is due to the direct execution of the Oracle stored procedure across the linked server. The code you provided (and I copied) executes the stored procedure in the server itself similar to an `OPENQUERY` statement. If you are trying to mask this syntax, I believe a new stored procedure in the local database may be the only way. If you truly want to use synonyms, you could always create one for the local SP.

Comment: @rdbradshaw It's not that I preferred synonyms to other methods; it just seemed like it would be the cleanest way based on how nicely they work for remote tables. Now it looks like they don't work at all for remote stored procedures. I've implemented your suggestion and it works great! Change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure in your local database that performs the operation

```
`EXECUTE ('BEGIN PROCEDURE1; END;') AT [LinkedOracleServer];`
```

This will combat the error of directly executing a stored procedure on a linked Oracle server while still masking the exact execution language.